# How do I set a listener in Awesomium? ("Field type 'Listener' is an abstract class" error)

Tags: c++, abstract-class, awesomium

I've been trying to get a Awesomium::WebViewListener working, but whenever I try to allocate the Listener object I get a "Field type 'Listener' is an abstract class" error.

Here's my code:

```
class Listener : public Awesomium::WebViewListener
{
public:
    void onCallback(Awesomium::WebView* caller,
                    const std::wstring& objectName,
                    const std::wstring& callbackName,
                    const Awesomium::JSArguments& args)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
    }
};

// In the GUI class
Listener listener; // Field type 'Listener' is an abstract class
view->setListener(&listener);
```

How am I supposed to set the listener if I can't allocate a Listener-object? I've tried using boost::shared_ptr which doesn't produce any errors but the onCallback()-function never gets called.

Comment: Does Awesomium::WebViewListener contain any abstract methods? If so you'll have to implement those...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be two variants:

1. `Awesomium::WebViewListener` contains more then one abstract method. If so - you should implement them all to create an instance of derived class `Listener' (bash.d said about it)
2. `Awesomium::WebViewListener::onCallback` arguments list should be exatly equal to your's one. If not so, then you **added** this method to `Listener`, but not implemented base abstract `onCallback`

Comment: Thanks! It worked when I implemented all of the virtual functions in Awesomium::WebViewListener!

Comment: IMHO it would be honest to ask @bash.d to make his comment as an answer and to vote it up (at least)